# Whats the correct way to programmatically include unpublished content in entity reference fields? (without views)

Tags: 8, users

I have a node reference field whose options get reduced to those nodes in which the current user is referenced:

```
function mymodule_process_form_field_project_ref(&$field) {
  $field['#required'] = true;
  $field['widget']['#required'] = true;
  $options = $field['widget']['#options'];

  $project_nids = mymodule_user_get_referenced_projects();

  foreach ($options as $key => $label) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
      if (!in_array($key, $project_nids)) {
        unset($options[$key]);
      }
    }
  }

  $field['widget']['#options'] = $options;

}
```

The problem is, in `$field['widget']['#options']` unpublished nodes are being removed in the first place. How to keep those? Do I have to define an own `ServiceProviderBase` class using the alter function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom EntityReferenceSelection plugin. 
Which should probably extend the [NodeSelection](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21EntityReferenceSelection%21NodeSelection.php/class/NodeSelection/8.2.x) plugin in core.